# Linq to filter result from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an existing function that returns a model data

```
var GetTableData = await _camService.GetTableData();
```

This returns a list `Task<List<GetTableDataModel>>` of model properties.

Now, I want to filter the result based on one of the model property (eg. email)

like,
GetTableData where `email='abc@email.com'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var filteredData = GetTableData.Where(x => x.email == "abc@email.com");
```

I would suggest you to create a function in which you will filter the data on the database side instead of querying all the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to perform filtering:

```
var filteredData = data.Where( item => item.email == "abc@email.com" ).ToArray();
```

In this case however I don't see the reason to retrieve all data at once when they are just filtered subsequently. I think it would be more efficient to filter them on the database side, within your service.

Comment: The reason being that I am not allowed to touch existing functionality so i figured instead of writing a new service,I would filter existing service method

Comment: But be aware that it can kill the performance in some point of time

Comment: Depending on the structure of the database, and how the model is setup, and depending on the use cases (high performance, low hardware specs, etc) you're right XardasLord.  A few things can help here - one is to avoid the use of virtual for eager loading of associated entities and the use of indexes - in this case on the table.  I'd argue that these two alone would scale pretty well to a point and may be enough to mitigate the OP's concerns since this sounds almost like an intranet application.